# I find ConfigurationSettings but not configurationManager

Tags: c#, config

I have created a Configuration file and are now trying to reach this in code when i look at the documentation about this it says that you should use configurationManager and not ConfigurationSettings but when i try to reach Manager i can only find settings? this is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration; 
namespace TextalkApi
{
    class AppHelper
    {
       public bool Save(string localServerPath, string apiDllLocation)
       {



       }
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Kl" value="v1"/>

  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Manager " in this context?

Comment: there is a class named Configuration manager that exist inside the System.Configuration library but i cant reach it

Comment: You need to install "System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Nuget package as ConfigurationManager resides in the assembly "System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install "System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Nuget package as ConfigurationManager resides in the assembly "System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager?view=netframework-4.8